# How can I create a TF-IDF for Text Classification using Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, tf-idf

I have a CSV file with the following format :

```
product_id1,product_title1
product_id2,product_title2
product_id3,product_title3
product_id4,product_title4
product_id5,product_title5
[...]
```

The product_idX is a integer and the product_titleX is a String, example :

```
453478692, Apple iPhone 4 8Go
```

I'm trying to create the TF-IDF from my file so I can use it for a Naive Bayes Classifier in MLlib.

I am using Spark for Scala so far and using the tutorials I have found on the official page and the Berkley AmpCamp [3](http://ampcamp.berkeley.edu/3/exercises/index.html) and [4](http://ampcamp.berkeley.edu/big-data-mini-course/movie-recommendation-with-mllib.html).

So I'm reading the file :

```
val file = sc.textFile("offers.csv")
```

Then I'm mapping it in tuples `RDD[Array[String]]`

```
val tuples = file.map(line => line.split(",")).cache
```

and after I'm transforming the tuples into pairs `RDD[(Int, String)]`

```
val pairs = tuples.(line => (line(0),line(1)))
```

But I'm stuck here and I don't know how to create the Vector from it to turn it into TFIDF.

Thanks

Comment: If I understand your problem well, each product can be present multiple times. This number of occurence of each product being your frequency (TF), I fail to understand what would be the IDF in your case. Could you please elaborate on that ?

Comment: tf–idf, short for term frequency–inverse document frequency, is a numerical statistic that is intended to reflect how important a word is to a document in a collection or corpus. It is often used as a weighting factor in information retrieval and text mining.

Comment: What I don't understand is that in your example, I see no mention of *collection or corpus*.

Comment: My last comment was the definition of a tf-idf, a collection or corpus is a group of documents on which you want to use data-mining techniques. In my case, we consider a CSV line as a document and the collection or corpus is the CSV file that contains these documents.

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't get it. Here is what I understand : 
you want the TF-IDF of each product. You have one product per line. You can have the same product multiple times.


Knowing that, and according to your last comment, the IDF of one product will be the inverse of the number of lines containing this product. In that case, what will be the TF ?

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't explain it to you in a comment. Please read [this](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/TF-IDF). It's in french

Comment: @eliasah Do you this should be marked as a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32672540/1560062?

Comment: I'd rather the question remain separated, you can write the part the answer concerning MLlib and I'll accept it!

Comment: @eliasah Did you ever find a good answer for this. Looking around the internet there isn't a good tutorial on how to use tf-idf in apache spark other than the scala docs

Comment: @Omnipresent I should probably take some time to write an answer for this one but I don't have much time lately.

Answer (score 8):

To do this myself (using pyspark), I first started by creating two data structures out of the corpus. The first is a key, value structure of

```
document_id, [token_ids]
```

The second is an inverted index like

```
token_id, [document_ids]
```

I'll call those corpus and inv_index respectively.

To get tf we need to count the number of occurrences of each token in each document. So

```python
from collections import Counter
def wc_per_row(row):
    cnt = Counter()
    for word in row:
        cnt[word] += 1
    return cnt.items() 

tf = corpus.map(lambda (x, y): (x, wc_per_row(y)))
```

The df is simply the length of each term's inverted index. From that we can calculate the idf.

```python
df = inv_index.map(lambda (x, y): (x, len(y)))
num_documnents = tf.count()

# At this step you can also apply some filters to make sure to keep
# only terms within a 'good' range of df. 
import math.log10
idf = df.map(lambda (k, v): (k, 1. + log10(num_documents/v))).collect()
```

Now we just have to do a join on the term_id:

```python
def calc_tfidf(tf_tuples, idf_tuples):
    return [(k1, v1 * v2) for (k1, v1) in tf_tuples for
        (k2, v2) in idf_tuples if k1 == k2]

tfidf = tf.map(lambda (k, v): (k, calc_tfidf(v, idf)))
```

This isn't a particularly performant solution, though. Calling collect to bring idf into the driver program so that it's available for the join seems like the wrong thing to do.

And of course, it requires first tokenizing and creating a mapping from each uniq token in the vocabulary to some token_id.

If anyone can improve on this, I'm very interested.