# How create a training file for Spark MLlib Naive Bayes and calculate TF–IDF

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, naivebayes

I need to classification a lot of products in a category tree,
I'm testing with Spark and Mlib Naive Bayes. But I don't understand how I can calculate the TF-IDF.

I have a trainer file like this:

```
#filenameTrainer:
103,355 4 50 60 71 72 66 73 57 53
103,35 45 55 65 75 85 66 73 57 53
104,355 41 51 61 71 72 67 73 58 54
```

etc.etc.

Where the first column is the category id, and the others are the words converted into an index.

this is the (pseudo) code than I use for training:

```
val conf = new SparkConf()
  .setAppName("SparseNaiveBayes test")
  .setMaster("local[1]")
  .set("spark.executor.memory", "2g")

val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val trainData = MLUtils.loadLabeledPoints(sc, filenameTrainer);
val trained:NaiveBayesModel = NaiveBayes.train(trainData);
```

well, if I try to search a category:

```
val testData:Vector =  Vectors.dense(Array[Double](3, 35,45,55,65,75,85,66,73,92 ))
val result:Double = trained.predict(testData)
println("Result = " + result)
```

The result is correct, it is return a category 103:
Result = 103.0

Now the question is, how can I calculate the TF–IDF for the trainer file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I create a TF-IDF for Text Classification using Spark?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24548290/how-can-i-create-a-tf-idf-for-text-classification-using-spark)

Comment: @eliasah yes, the question is similar, do you have resolved? the answers did not solve the problem

Comment: Did you read the answers? The given answers are a good start. I actually solved it but I didn't have time to write a proper explained answer