# How to split into train, test and evaluation sets in sklearn?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

It's my first time doing classification, sorry in advance for my ignorance.

I have some data and it seems easy to [split into train and test sets with Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31521170/scikit-learn-train-test-split-with-indices).

Is there a way to split into train, test and evaluation sets instead?

Comment: You can do this in `sklearn` using `sklearn.cross_validation.train_test_split`. The duplicate post that this was linked to was for using numpy/pandas. http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.train_test_split.html

Comment: @ode2k thanks for your comment, isn't that the very same function my linked question uses?

Comment: Actually, the answer in the linked question uses numpy to split into the 3 sets that you are asking for. I guess sklearn only does the training / test sets, not evaluation set. So if you are able to use numpy for splitting them up, that is a good solution.

Comment: Yeah I think I will go for it, thank you @ode2k!